# NSURL fileReferenceURL becomes invalid after file update?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsurl

My app needs to keep references to files that remain valid even when the files are moved or updated. In the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html) they recommend using NSURL's fileReferenceURL. This works fine for when the files are moved, but the references become invalid when the files are updated. I'm wondering if there's some good solution for this. Below is a simple tester app that confirms my finding:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import AppKit;

int exists(NSURL *url) {
    NSLog(@"path %@", url.path);
    NSLog(@"ref  %@", url.absoluteString);
    NSError *error;
    BOOL value = [url checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&error];
    if(error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"File not reachable: %@", error);
    }
    NSLog(@"exists == %@", value ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    return value? 1: 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *path = @"./test.txt";
        NSURL *pathUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        NSURL *refUrl = pathUrl.fileReferenceURL;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:refUrl.path contents:nil attributes:nil];

        exists(pathUrl); // yes
        exists(refUrl);  // yes

        // this second call must update the file
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:refUrl.path contents:nil attributes:nil];
        exists(pathUrl); // yes
        exists(refUrl);  // no. refUrl.path is nil, and the file cannot be reached

        refUrl = pathUrl.fileReferenceURL;
        exists(refUrl);  // yes, since it's a new file reference
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the `writeToURL:...`, `writeToFile:...`, or `replaceItemAtURL:...` methods, instead? Those should properly update an existing file, rather than deleting and recreating as you're doing. Otherwise, you should use bookmark data for robustness beyond file reference URLs.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your comments. The files I'm tracking are outside of the app's control, so they can be updated by any means. I ran into this when the file is updated in the TextEdit app. Good advice on the bookmarks, and that's my current workaround. I was just wondering if there was something I'm missing, especially since the bookmarks don't suffer from this issue.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a bookmark. See [Locating Files Using Bookmarks](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html)

Comment: Thanks guys, it looks like bookmarks are the way to go. I wasn't sure if they were just for saving to disk. I'd like to mark that as the answer so if you come back to this feel free to write an official reply.